Why are these characters seeking emotional validation at that moment in the story?
In Fast X (2023), Isabel arrives at a beach party in her sports car. Dom comments that she
must be in the winner’s circle tonight and asks if she put an RB26 engine
in her car. Isabel responds that an L24 engine would never handle this
much boost. Dom mentions that his friend back home would approve, but
Isabel states that she’s not looking for anyone’s approval:

Dom: Before you get ahead of yourself, look around you. We're all
looking for a little validation.
Isabel: You racing or what?

Diogo speaks to Isabel:

Diogo: Trust me, you don't want that smoke.
Dom: I'm not here for pink slips tonight.

Why these characters are seeking emotional validation at that moment in the story?

It's not clear to me whether or not you're aware of the concept of emotional validation. Everyone wants emotional validation because it's an aspect of human society and interpersonal relations. That is what is meant by "We're all looking for a little validation." Are you asking why these characters are seeking emotional validation at that moment in the story?

@ToddWilcox  Are you asking why these characters are seeking emotional validation at that moment in the story?  YES.

Some believe everyone is always seeking emotional validation.

In the Fast & Furious franchise, you have 'beautiful' (depends on your taste for cars though) and very fast cars, beautiful women with character (and sometimes with an attitude), and smart and strong guys (bad boys often with an attitude). They're most of the time seeking recognition by seeking attention. In their world, image is everything. They want to draw attention: the cars, the fashion and the attitude are part of the game.
I wouldn't classify this as 'emotional validation' because emotional validation is more about the individual's inner emotional experience.
The way they show off is a way to look for self-satisfaction, self-appreciation, or self-approval. Many of them don't come from wealthy families like the Tran's. They have or had to work their way out, and they need to be recognized as such. The cars, the clothes and the attitude are what they want to be recognized by their peers and others as a proof of their strenght/success.

Maybe they have been compared with others from their early ages and they feel in need of comparison to decide either to satisfy with what they have or not. Or maybe by this way they measure the value of their successes and self-sufficiency. (emphasis mine)

But for what you ask ('at that moment in the story'), it doesn't seem to be much more than this, with no real importance for the plot. It's not specifically here that they behave like that, it's almost everytime and in every movie of the franchise.
She's not looking for pink slips (meaning, not here to race and win), which is what they're usually doing to get recognizion by winning money, impressing others, and gaining respect.
For some of them may also have some kind of HPD.
